# Dropping or Updating Duplicate Values in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have put a unique index on my database table for `steamid`. I am unsure how I can insert a record with duplicate values for this key (dropping the old record) without getting an error.  Could someone edit my code to make it suitable, Thanks.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO steam_data (reg_date, reg_year, steamname, steamid) VALUES ('$dateoutput', '$dateoutputyear', '$personaname', '$steamid')";
```

The error is :

> Error: INSERT INTO steam_data (reg_date, reg_year, steamname, steamid)
>   VALUES ('March 20, 07:09pm', '2017', 'Aweosmedude',
>   '76561113498123831721') Duplicate entry '76561113498123831721' for key
>   'steamid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you already have a record in your `steam_data` table with `streamid=76561113498123831721`; and you have a constraint in your schema that ensures that you don't have more than one `streamid`. So you can either do `INSERT IGNORE INTO stream_data...` or do `INSERT INTO stream_data...ON DUPLICATE KEY...`

e.g.

`INSERT INTO steam_data (reg_date, reg_year, steamname, steamid) VALUES ('$dateoutput', '$dateoutputyear', '$personaname', '$steamid') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname=VALUES(steamname);`

(@ReneS answer has example of `INSERT IGNORE INTO...`)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for, though if the data exists for steamid, update the steamname value, are you able to create some code quickly for that? Thanks!

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE steamname=VALUES(steamname)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO steam_data (reg_date, reg_year, steamname, steamid) VALUES ('$dateoutput', '$dateoutputyear', '$personaname', '$steamid')";
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option is the [`REPLACE` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html):

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

```
REPLACE INTO steam_data (reg_date, reg_year, steamname, steamid) VALUES ('$dateoutput', '$dateoutputyear', '$personaname', '$steamid')
```

(I sure hope you're not actually inserting data into your database with a query like that. Use prepared statements!)